# Is this a valid HCI UART command?

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth controller via 5-wire UART on a bare metal system. I am trying to send the following packet as HCI reset. The HCI extension for Logic2 says the command is unknown, and the controller does not respond to the command at all. What am I getting wrong?

[image: HCI reset command Logic2 view]

P.S.: I am using a [Mango Pi MQ-Pro](https://mangopi.org/mqpro), connecting to a [Realtek 8723DS](https://mangopi.org/_media/rtl8723ds-cg_datasheet_0.92_20170804.pdf) (the shell label is [FN-Link 6223A-SRD](https://mangopi.org/_media/fn-link_fg6223asrd_datasheet_v2.1_20210728.pdf)).

Comment: Hardware handshake enabled?